# Wordpress downloadable files redirect to file not found

Tags: wordpress, download

I have a website with digital downloadable products. Sometimes the links just don't work and customers see file not found. Go to shop

I have tried switching from force downloads to redirect only. This method helped for one product only

I wonder if there is any way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You need to check some steps to resolve this issue. Such as

- Check the file path
- Check file permissions
- Check the download link
- Use a file hosting service
- Monitor your website logs

i hope this checklist might helpful. Thank u

Comment: Thank tou for your reply
I have checked the file path and the download...the directories are just fine
permissions are allowed as well, also the files are in the hosting file manager